# CSS Linear gradient borders

Tags: css, syntax, border, gradient

I am trying to use a CSS3 Border gradient property and using an example from css tricks. I can get it to work using their example but cant seem to get my colours in that i am after and i think it's syntax errors. Is someone able to let me know what i may be missing?

I am after a left and right border on a div with the gradient going from `#d1d2cd` to `#e3e4df` `5 pixels` wide?

I have mocked up an example in js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DqgPy/

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?? http://jsfiddle.net/DqgPy/1/

Comment: Nearly, i am after the gradient applied to the right and left as a border on the div, not the body. From your code though i have created a gradient with these colours but it's coloured the div rather than applying it as a border? It's great how many browser compatibility options you have added! http://jsfiddle.net/DqgPy/2/

Comment: so you want the border to have gradient??

Comment: Yeah :) just the left and right from dark to light, the 1st link in my question is exactly what i am after but when i add my own hex or rgb values in it breaks, i think its something to do when im deleting the black and duplicating the rgb brackets in?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out a site like:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Play around with the gradient settings, and it will auto-generate the CSS you need (including support for older browsers). At the very least, the code provided might help you figure out any of your syntax errors.